# Kendo Multi-Calendar in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, calendar

I'm trying to create an angular directive that manages 3 kendo calendars on a web page.  The idea is to have it highlight dates over the next 3 months of activity.  We've had no luck getting access to the kendo methods that are available for the calendar, specifically navigate().  [Burke Holland](https://plus.google.com/+BurkeHolland/posts) has a nice [article](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/14-02-26/a-few-angular-kendo-ui-best-practices) on angular best practices for kendo UI elements and suggests the follow:

```
<div kendo-grid="grid" ...></div>

<script>
    function HomeCtrl($scope) {

     $scope.refresh = function() {
     // scope.grid is the widget reference
     $scope.grid.refresh();
     }
}
</script>
```

But this is not working in the home.js file containing the home controller.

Here is the html

```
<div kendo-calendar="calendar1" data-k-options="homevm.calendar1Config"></div>
```

And here is the controller code.

```
        $scope.navigate1 = function (date) {
            $scope.calendar1.navigate(date);
        }
```

An object is created but `$scope.calendar1` comes out as undefined at runtime.

We've several approaches to getting access to the kendo calendar object in order to call the `navigate()` method but have only had success using JQuery in a html inline script.  We've tried creating the kendo calendar using `document.createElement()` and saving that in collection but it is a javascript simple element object not has a kendo calendar.  Does anyone know how we can cast that as a kendo calendar?  Or get a reference to the kendo calendar object in the angular controller?  Or maybe has anyone done a directive for a multi-calendar object in angular?

Answer (score 0):

try to create container object in scope , and then
sets the kendo name like this:

### in the controller:

```
$scope.container = {};
```

### in the html:

```
<div kendo-calendar="container.calendar1" data-k-options="homevm.calendar1Config"></div>
```

Hope it helps